# How does softmax loss works in multi-task learning

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, multitasking, softmax

I got a little bit lost while studying loss functions for multi-task learning.

For instance, in binary classification with only one task, for example classifying emails as spam or not, the sum of probabilities for each label (spam/not spam) would be 1 using softmax activation + softmax_crossentropy loss function. How does that apply to multi-task learning?

Let's consider the case with 5 tasks and each of them is a binary problem. Is the softmax function applied to each task  independently (e.g. for task 1: probability of label 1 = 0.7 and label 2 = 0.3; for task 2: probability of label 1 = 0.2 and label 2 = 0.8 and so on) or it considers the tasks jointly (e.g. if label 1 of task 1 has a probability of 0.80 all other labels of all other tasks will sum to 0.20)?

Answer (score 3):

Some notes:

1. Nitpicking: you should not use softmax for binary classification, but rather a regular sigmoid (which is kind of the 2d reduction of the softmax), followed by a log-loss (same).
2. for mulit-task that involves classification, you would probably use multiple binary classifications. Say you have an image and you want an output to say if there are pedestrians, cars and road signs in it. This is not a multi-class classification, as an image can have all of the above in it. So instead you'd define your output as 3 nodes, and you would calculate the binary classification for each node. This is done in one multi-task NN instead of running 3 different NN's, with the assumption that all 3 classification problems can benefit from the same latent layer or embedding that is created in that one NN.

Comment: What if the single tasks are not binary? How the architecture should change?

Comment: Assume there are 2 tasks. First task is binary classification task like whether there are any pedestrians. Second is a multi-class classification task like weather is sunny, cloudy or dark. Therefore, your network should output (1 + 3) 4 nodes. First node should be applied a BCE (sigmoid) loss and 2nd to 4th nodes should be connected to a CE loss. You can assume to be splitting output node into 2 different outputs and applying 2 different losses.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, the loss function that is calculated can be different for different tasks in the case of multi-task(I would like to comment that it is not MULTI-LABEL classification) classification.
For example, Task 1 can be binary classification; Task 2 can be next sentence prediction and so on. Therefore, since different tasks involves learning different Loss function, you can attribute to the first part of your assumption, i.e, Softmax is applied only to the labels of the first task, while learning the first task.